# How to call fetch_feed function from plugin in functions.php (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm using the 'RSS Feed Block (Gutenberg)' plugin on my wordpress site, which I use to display a feed. However, if I update the feed, the plugin only shows the updates the next day. I would like the plugin to refresh the feed instantly, or at least more than once a day.

The plugin comes with a few hooks, for instance:

```
grf_before_items -- called before displaying the feed on your site.

grf_before_item -- called before each feed entry.
```

In the code I find a function that is used to fetch the feed:

```
class GRF_Helper {
    
    /**
     * The main method used for fetching a feed.
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @return object
     */ 
    static function fetch_feed($url) {  
        return fetch_feed($url);
    }   
}
```

So I tried:

```
add_action('grf_before_items', 'GRF_Helper');
```

in functions.php. But that doesn't work. Can anyone help me out or give some pointers on where to search for?

(code from plugin: https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/rss-feed-block/)

Comment: Are you sure that "posts not showing in feed until the next day" isn't just the web browser caching the RSS feed?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, unfortunately that's not it :( I've cleared my cache multiple times and tried different browsers/devices but the posts don't show.

Comment: Took a second look at the code and noticed that it uses the [fetch_feed()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/fetch_feed/) function. Its [More Information](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/fetch_feed/#more-information) section states that "fetch_feed caches results for 12 hours by default", so maybe this is where you should start. You'll find there a link to a filter hook to change the lifespan of said cache to, for example, 1 hour.